# Oracle Text Contains and technical content

Tags: oracle, lexer, oracle11gr2, oracle-text

I'am searching for the technical word "AN-XYZ99". So I use

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE CONTAINS(bar, 'AN{-}XYZ99') > 0
```

but I get also results like "FO-XYZ99" or "BAR-XYZ99". What can I do to ensure the expected result?

I used

```
BEGIN
    CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE('FOO','BASIC_LEXER');
    CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE('FOO', 'ALTERNATE_SPELLING', 'GERMAN');
    CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE('FOO', 'COMPOSITE', 'GERMAN');
    CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE('FOO', 'MIXED_CASE', 'NO');
END;
```

Sample data from column "bar" (VARCHAR2(4000)):

```
"unbekannt Stadt Text: AN-XYZ99 << foobar Straße 31.12.2017 Datum Host 20160101 foo"
"unbekannt Stadt Text: FO-XYZ99 << foobar Straße 31.12.2017 Datum Host 20160101 bar"
"unbekannt Stadt Text: BAR-XYZ99 << foobar Straße 31.12.2017 Datum Host 20160101 bla"
```

With the Statement above I would like the first row as output but I get the second and third row as well.

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: are you specifically search single word ? or do you have any pattern ?

Comment: @Ravi: The single word mentioned above without any patterns.

Comment: Then, why are you using pattern there ? ?

Comment: Please sample data from your table and your expected output, to make your question more clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must define hyphen as a `printjoin` in your lexer.

check it with

```
select IXV_ATTRIBUTE, IXV_VALUE from CTXSYS.CTX_INDEX_VALUES where IXV_CLASS =  'LEXER';

IXV_ATTRIBUTE                  IXV_VALUE     
-----------------------------------------
PRINTJOINS                     _$%&-         
NUMJOIN                        .              
NUMGROUP                       .              
WHITESPACE                     ,=
```

Then you may (after re-creating index with this lexer) validate that the tokens are as expected: (your table would vary based on the index name; check all tables like 'DR$%$I')

```
select TOKEN_TEXT from DR$TEXTIDX_IDX$I where TOKEN_TEXT like '%-XYZ99';
TOKEN_TEXT                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------
AN-XYZ99                                                         
BAR-XYZ99                                                        
FO-XYZ99
```

Now you may query for the search string.

Aparently you must escape the hyphen as `BAR-XYZ99` will find rows with `BAR` **not** containing `XYZ99` ; although the [documentation of `hyphen with no space`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#CBACAGCF) is a bit different.

```
SELECT SCORE(1),txt
FROM textidx
WHERE  CONTAINS(txt, 'BAR-XYZ99',1) > 0; 

  SCORE(1) TXT                                                                                
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         4 unbekannt Stadt Text: FO-XYZ99 << foobar Straße 31.12.2017 Datum Host 20160101 bar
```

For some reason (I'm on 11.2.0.2.0) the escaping with curly braces doesn't work (returns no match), but using backslash is fine.

```
SELECT SCORE(1),txt
FROM textidx
WHERE  CONTAINS(txt, 'BAR\-XYZ99',1) > 0;  

  SCORE(1) TXT                                                                                
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         4 unbekannt Stadt Text: BAR-XYZ99 << foobar Straße 31.12.2017 Datum Host 20160101 bla
```